# Automatically create associations through many existing associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dynamic, associations, ruby-on-rails-3.2, has-many-through

I'm working on an engine where any model can have a has_many association with Permit as Permissible:

```
class Permit < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :permissible, polymorphic: true
end

module Permissible
  def self.included(base)
    base.class_eval do
    has_many :permits, as: :permissible
  end
end

class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Permissible
end

class GroupAllocation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :person
  belongs_to :group
end

class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Permissible
  has_many :group_allocations
  has_many :groups, through: :group_allocations
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :person
end
```

So, Group has_many :permits and Person has_many :permits. What I am trying to do is dynamically create associations on User that uses the permits association as a source, and chain associations on other models down to User by doing the same. This can be done manually (in rails 3.1+) with:

```
class Person
  has_many :group_permits, through: :person, source: :permits
end

class User
  has_many :person_permits, through: :person, source: :permits, class_name: Permit
  has_many :person_group_permits, through: :person, source: :group_permits, class_name: Permit
end
```

However, in practice, Permissible will be included on many models, so I'm trying to write a class method on User (actually within another module, but no need to confuse things more) that can traverse User.reflect_on_all_associations and create an array of new associations, which may be many associations deep each.

Looking for input on how to do this cleanly in rails 3.2.8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I did it (implementation code varies slightly from the details given in the question):

module Authorisable
    def self.included(base)
      base.class_eval do
        base.extend ClassMethods
      end
    end

```
module ClassMethods
  class PermissionAssociationBuilder
    def build_permissions_associations(klass)
      chains = build_chains_from(klass)
      chains.select! {|c| c.last.klass.included_modules.include? DistributedAuthorisation::Permissible}
      permissions_associations = []
      chains.each do |chain|
        source_name = :permissions
        chain.reverse.each do |r|
          assoc_name = :"#{r.name}_#{source_name}"
          r.active_record.has_many assoc_name, through: r.name.to_sym, source: source_name, class_name: DistributedAuthorisation::Permission
          source_name = assoc_name
        end
        permissions_associations << source_name
      end
      return permissions_associations
    end

    private

    def build_chains_from(klass)
      chains = reflections_to_follow(klass).map {|r| [r]}
      chains.each do |chain|
        models = chain.map {|r| r.klass}.unshift klass
        reflections_to_follow(models.last).each do |r|
          chains << (chain.clone << r) unless models.include? r.klass
        end
      end
    end

    def reflections_to_follow(klass)
      refs = klass.reflect_on_all_associations
      refs.reject {|r| r.options[:polymorphic] or r.is_a? ActiveRecord::Reflection::ThroughReflection}
    end
  end

  def permissions_associations
    @permissions_associations ||= PermissionAssociationBuilder.new.build_permissions_associations(self)
  end
end
```

Probably not the most efficient method, but it adds the chains I'm after with Klass.permissions_associations, and stores their symbols in class instance variable.

I'd be happy to hear suggestions on how to improve it.